# accessing JIRA rest API over ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I was trying to write a ruby script which would use the rest API.
However am stuck at the auth step ( am using basic auth ).

From what I thought I understood i was supposed to base 64 encode my login:password then pass it with header Authorization along with my 
request but its getting me nowhere but 403 forbidden errors.

```
enc   = Base64.encode64('username:passs')
my_url = 'http://intenthq.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/application-properties'
my_key = 'Basic '+ enc
puts enc
puts 'Authorization ' + my_key
RestClient::Request.execute(
 :method => :get,
 :url => my_url,
 :headers => {'Authorization' => my_key}
)
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Am I even using the correct methods ?

Comment: You can try using this gem https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby, that should make everything easier for you.

Comment: Oh thanks Coderhs, I gave it a second try :D
it seems to have authed me this time , must have made a mistake the first time.

Answer (score 1):

managed to sort it out by using github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby
thanks Coderhs :)